# Validate template parameter is other defined template

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

How can I test that OtherFoo template parameter (for my TT alias) is Foo with other template parameters:

```
template <class... Pack>
class Foo
{

    class SomeClass {};

    template <class OtherFoo> // OtherFoo = Foo with other template parameters
    using TT = typename OtherFoo::SomeClass;
};
```

It is assumed that it is impossible to do spoofing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a partial specialization, like that:

```
template <class... Pack>
class Foo
{
    class SomeClass {};

    template <class OtherFoo>  // OtherFoo = anything, but undefined
    struct TT_t;

    template <class... P> // OtherFoo = Foo with other template parameters
    struct TT_t <Foo <P...> > { using type = typename Foo <P...>::SomeClass };

    template <class OtherFoo> // OtherFoo = Foo with other template parameters
    using TT = typename TT_t <OtherFoo>::type;
};
```

So if you try to instantiate `TT` with any parameter other than another `Foo`, the compiler will issue an error, saying that `TT_t` is an incomplete type. I hope this is what you were after.

Comment: It seems that it works. Could you explain how the partial specialization in this case?

Comment: I am not sure I follow your question. Anyhow the general `X` is declared with arbitrary parameter `OtherFoo` but not defined so. A specialization is defined only for the case where `OtherFoo` is of the form `Foo <P...>` *for some* parameters `P...`, which are automatically deduced if so. In this case, `Foo <P...>` is `OtherFoo` of course, so by appending `::SomeClass` we just "read off" its nested class `SomeClass` (which all `Foo`'s are guaranteed to have). I hope this is a bit clearer. You could do some reading, e.g. [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html).